# Can't get UWP content dialog to size properly

Tags: uwp, dialog, size

I can't get my UWP dialogs to exceed some fixed width. This app has been in production a few years, but after this last update, the dialogs are all some strange fixed width. I am using MVVM light and did just update to 5.4.1 but I am just calling dialog objects subclassed from ContentDialog. As I mentioned, this has been working just fine for 1.5 years or so, not sure why it just stopped working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

xaml code follows:

```
SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
Width="Auto"
MinWidth="1000"
Opened="ContentDialog_Opened"
Closed="ContentDialog_Closed"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=ClockDialog}">

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="900">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" MinWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" MinWidth="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,6" Text="Type:" Style="{StaticResource CCBlackTextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,8"  Text="Mfg:" Style="{StaticResource CCBlackTextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Comment: Tracked this down a bit more, I have a very simple blank UWP app with two identical dialogs. One has a MinWidth setting for the dialog, the other does not. They both look identical in the designer, and when running the app. No change at all. Question: Shouldn't they be different?

Comment: The actual dialog box does not seem to change size at all. No matter what I do.

Comment: Using MVVM Light, the dialogs respond to the MinWidth in both the designer and at runtime. So it sure seems like a style issue, but I tried looking at this in Blend and got nowhere.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by @Tom, I copied the MaxWidth and MaxHeight keys into the App Resources, and changed to my desired values.  No other parts of the style were needed.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxWidth">1200</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxHeight">800</x:Double>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default Style for ContentDialog imposes a MaxHeight of 184 and MaxWidth of 548:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx

Perhaps this was added or changed in the update like you suspect.  To override the style properties try something like:

```
<Grid Name="MyContainer">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentDialog" x:Key="largeDialaog">
            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="720" />
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1280" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentDialog Style="{StaticResource largeDialog}">
        <!--your content goes here-->
    </ContentDialog>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you saying overriding those two properties didn't work? You shouldn't have to copy and paste the entire style AFAIK.

Comment: I had some issues with background of ContentDialog, and changing MinWidth / MinHeight / MaxWidth / MaxHeight fixed those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous response, I started looking at the style for ContentDialog. I could not find a default style using blend, so just decided to create my own. All I did was copy the style posted here [Documented style for ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx) to my own style library and then applied it to all my ContentDialog screens. That did the trick and I am back in business. I suspect that something is missing from the latest VS update I applied just a few days ago.